# A self-invoking function is not called

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout

I have a problem - I wrote a mini function to the counter on the page. The assumption is that the value is incremented by one at some timeout, unfortunately - nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```js
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);

subscribers = function() {
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML++;
  setTimeout(subscribers, 300);
}
```

```html
<p id="counter"></p>
```

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `subscribers` anywhere. What makes you think it's a self-invoking function?

Comment: This isnt a self ivoking function. Its a function assigned to a variable you need to do subscribers() to ivoke it.

Comment: Yup, where's that function invoked?

Answer (score 1):

Chicken and edd: `subscribers()` calls itself, but you *still need* to call it the first time.

```js
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);

subscribers = function() {
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML++;
  setTimeout(subscribers, 1000);
}

subscribers(); // <-- Start your loop.
```

```html
<p id="counter"></p>
```

That said, a much more idiomatic solution is to use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval):

```js
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);

setInterval(() => document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML++, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="counter"></p>
```

Comment: Darn, you seem to have beat me by 2 seconds! +1 and I'm deleting mine :P

Comment: @HyperNeutrino If it makes you feel better, in my 8 years here, I think this is the first time I've 'won' a [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite).

Comment: Ah okay ;P Don't worry, I'm not sad or anything, I come from PPCG and FGITWs is so common there that I'm used to it xD

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Sweet! I've been contributing to `05AB1E` but can't use it for anything fun yet.

Answer (score 1):

The term for that function is a "recursive" function, and recursive functions don't automatically invoke themselves out of the blue.

If you really did want to define and invoke it in the same place, then you can turn it into an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE):

```js
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);

(function subscribers() {
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML++;
  setTimeout(subscribers, 300);
})();
```

```html
<p id="counter"></p>
```